# Detect properties non in JSON when deserializing with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to make a tool which will compare JSON objects with some C# POCO objects I have. This tool will help me detect when new fields are added or old ones removed compared to my objects.

The "new field" case is simple. In the `SerializerSettings` I set the `MissingMemberHandling` property to `Error` and add a listener to the `Error` event. When an C# field is missing, the event is called with details.

The "old field" case (where a C# field/property isn't set) seems to be harder to solve. See the example code below. This code will run without issues, and detect cases when a new JSON field appears, but will not detect when `Field2` is not in the JSON.

```
class TestObject
{
    public int Field1 { get; set; }

    public int Field2 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string exampleJson = @"{ ""Field1"": 1 }";

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        settings.Error = Error;

        try
        {
            TestObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(exampleJson, settings);

            Console.WriteLine("Object had no errors");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object had errors");
        }
    }

    private static void Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Path + " had " + errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing Contract Resolvers (and settings callbacks for deserializing) but they don't get called for each field (only for each type)...

Lastly. I cannot add `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]` or `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a workable solution.

By creating a `ContractResolver`, I can set all properties to `Required` at runtime. This will give an error without changing my model, but it only gives the first error ... unless you set `Handled` to `true` in the `Error` callback:

```
class TestObject
{

    public int Field1 { get; set; }

    public int Field2 { get; set; }

    public int Field3 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string exampleJson = @"{ ""Field1"": 1, ""Field4"": 1 }";

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        settings.ContractResolver = new ContractResolver();
        settings.Error = Error;

        try
        {
            TestObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestObject>(exampleJson, settings);

            Console.WriteLine("Object had no errors");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object had errors");
        }
    }

    private static void Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs errorEventArgs)
    {
        errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        Console.WriteLine(errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Path + " had " + errorEventArgs.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
    }
}

internal class ContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty res = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        res.Required = Required.AllowNull;

        return res;
    }
}
```